# How to dynamically create upload path for media files django-ckeditor?

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I am using **RichTextUploadingField** in my model.

I have set upload path to `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"`

I use this field when I am on path:
`path("<slug:p_slug>/<slug:m_slug>/<slug:slug>/edit_feature/", views.EditFeature.as_view(), name="edit_feature"),`

I want the path of the file looks like this, after adding a file:`media/<slug:p_slug>/<slug:m_slug>/<slug:slug>/<file_name>/`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have a solution
I copied whole ckeditor_uploader into my django project directory

In ckeeditor_uploader\views.py get_upload_filename I added:

```
def get_upload_filename(upload_name, request):
    referrer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
    http_origin = request.META.get('HTTP_ORIGIN') + "/"
    referrer = referrer.replace(http_origin, "")
```

And then I modified upload_path in this function (referrer at the end)

```
upload_path = os.path.join(settings.CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH, user_path, date_path, referrer)
```

More on request.META [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)